# Github transfer contributions from one account to another

Tags: github

I have googled it a lot but didn't find any clear answer if it possible and how to do it.

I have an account from which I have contributions to a private repo. I don't have any repositories.

I want all those contributions to go to my new account (There I have repositories).

Is that possible? Do I still have access to that private repo after transfer the contributions?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to rewrite commits which would create new hashes (the committer's name is part of the data used to calculate the hash).

This would mean all commits that reference these commits (the parent commits also being part of the data used to calculate the hash) would also need to be regenerated (`rebase` allows this to be done in bulk).

All of this would require forcing pushes as well (so all other contributor's local repositories are going to be impacted).

Even if github can automate some of this, it is a massive impact.

TL;DR: yes, but you probably should accept it is hard to rewrite history.

Comment: So If I merge the 2 accounts the contribution will not merged?

Comment: @roliroli Certainly the content of the repository won't be updated (GitHub might alias things, but that's not the underlying data).

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from the tags I assume you're talking about GitHub accounts. GitHub calculates contributions based on the author email address used in Git commits, and if there is a GitHub account that uses this email address, your GitHub user name shows up as a contributor. That said, you can associate multiple email addresses with a single GitHub account. So if you unregister your current email address from your old GitHub account, and register the same email address for your new GitHub account, existing contributions will show under your new GitHub account.

> Do I still have access to that private repo after transfer the contributions?

That's a totally different question, and the answer depends on whether your new GitHub account was given access to the private repository. The GitHub permissions system is based on the GitHub user name, not on registered email addresses.

Comment: The problem is that the accounts using different email addresses.

Comment: Like I tried to state above, that should not be a problem. When logged in under your new account, just go to https://github.com/settings/emails and use "Add email address" to also add the email address from your old account here. It *might* be that you need to remove that email address from your old account first, though, as I assume GitHub checks that a single email address is not registered with two accounts at the same time.

Comment: So I removed the mail from old account I added it to the new one I clicked the checkbox to show private contributions but the contribution do not show at all

Comment: You might need to give it some time, GitHub may only update these statistics once a day or so.

Comment: @GabrielVasile nope!

Comment: @Roland have you had any luck with this? I changed email, the private repo shows the correct github user (the new one) but still does not show in contributions graph.

Comment: @chimera I gave up on that after spending a lot of time

Answer (score -1):

Use one of these projects:

- https://github.com/kefimochi/sync-contribution-graph
- https://github.com/charpeni/sync-external-contributions

They're pretty similar in scope and functionality.